# É possível aplicar o grupo móvel na frase "O João, silenciosamente, saiu de casa"?

Tags: gramática, frases

É possível aplicar o grupo móvel na frase "O João, silenciosamente, saiu de casa"?

Em que situações podemos aplicar o Grupo Móvel numa frase ?

Comment: O que é esse grupo móvel de que perguntas? Ao perguntares "como ficaria [a frase, ao incluir esse grupo móvel]", entendo que o grupo não está ainda na frase. Mas o grupo móvel não é "silenciosamente"? Será que estás a perguntar... não se é possível aplicar *o* grupo móvel (qual?), mas se a frase pode ser construída como a construiste; é isto?

Comment: Você se refere à intercalação do advérbio de modo?

Comment: Sim, aplicar o grupo móvel na frase. A frase pode ser construída de que outras formas.?Em que situações podermos aplicar o Grupo Móvel numa frase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na forma canônica, geralmente, o advérbio aparece depois do verbo, sem vírgulas, pois (nesse caso) o advérbio especifica o modo do verbo (como?).

> "O João saiu silenciosamente de casa"
>
> - Saiu como?
>
> - Silenciosamente.

Como temos dois adverbios (de modo e de lugar) a frase admite muitas construções:

> "O João saiu de casa silenciosamente"
>
> - Saiu de onde?
>
> - De casa.

Em inglês existe uma ordem correta para colocação dos advérbios, mas em português, desconheço a existência de tal regra.

Quando se altera a ordem natural dos termos, deve-se denotar por vírgula:

> "Silenciosamente, o João saiu de casa"
>
> "O João, silenciosamente, saiu de casa"
>
> "De casa, João saiu silenciosamente"
>
> "O João, de casa, saiu silenciosamente"
>
> "Silenciosamente, de casa, saiu o João"
>
> "De casa, silenciosamente, saiu o João"

Todas as formas acimas são aceitáveis, mas nem todas são aprazíveis.

Usa-se o recurso de inversão para que o interlocutor interprete de certa maneira.

Ao dizer:

> "João saiu de casa silenciosamente"

O interlocutor primeiro visualiza João, saindo de casa e por último recebe a informação que foi de modo silencioso. Ao inverter a frase, o interpretador primeiro visualiza que foi de um modo silencioso e logo em seguida descobre o quê.

Comment: Muito boa explicação

Comment: Sem virgulas ficaria "O João saiu de casa silenciosamente". certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo, ou `O joão saiu silenciosamente de casa`.